# Excel VBA how to include cell content on change in email body

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

Hello fellow coders and knowledge seekers. I have this code that is sending an email informing that a date has been added to a cell in J column (Submittal Date). I just want to include the content of a cell in column B (Submittal title) corresponding to that date that has been added.

The code is working fine and sending an email when I add a date in a cell in column J. But I want to add that submittal title in the body of the email. Here is my code

```
  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Dim SubmitLink As Range

    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("J3:J1000")
    Set SubmitLink = Range("B3:B1000")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
       Is Nothing Then

        ' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been
        ' changed.
        ' Place your code here.
        Dim answer As String

        answer = MsgBox("Do you wish to save this change. An Email will be sent to the User", vbYesNo, "Save the change")

        If answer = vbNo Then Cancel = True
        If answer = vbYes Then
            'open outlook type stuff
            Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set OlObjects = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
            Set newmsg = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
            'add recipients
            'newmsg.Recipients.Add ("Name Here")
            newmsg.Recipients.Add Worksheets("Coordinator").Range("Q4").Value
            'add subject
            newmsg.Subject = Worksheets("Coordinator").Range("O3").Value
            'add body
            newmsg.Body = "Dear User, New Submittal" & Cells(SubmitLink.Row, "B") & "has been Added in SUBMITTAL Log. Please Investigate the Change"
            newmsg.Display    'display
            newmsg.Send    'send message
            'give conformation of sent message
            MsgBox "Modification confirmed", , "Confirmation"



        End If
        '     MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."

    End If
End Sub
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Confusing description.  Anyhow just look in this line and change accordingly (newmsg.Body = "Dear User, New Submittal" & Cells(SubmitLink.Row, "B") & "has been Added in Musanda ICA online Log. Please Investigate the Change")

Comment: First, thank you for your reply. You are right. I will rephrase. I just want my code to send an email whenever I am adding a new submittal date. And in the body of this email I want to add the title of this submittal. Column J is where I input submittal dates, and column B is where I input submittal titles.

Comment: Can you add a snapshot of what your spreadsheet looks like and what changes you want to the body?  I **sort of** get what you're saying, but not exactly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I got the solution, I will post it for others benefit also :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution. Just define the cell you want to retrieve the data from

```
Dim SubmitLink As String
```

Then identify this cell's offset from the KeyCell

```
SubmitLink = Target.Offset(, -8).Value
```

And finally add ( " & SubmitLink & " ) in the text of the email body or title, and the data in that cell will appear. And here is the full code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim KeyCells As Range


    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("J3:J1000")


    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

        ' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been
        ' changed.
        ' Place your code here.
Dim answer As String
Dim SubmitLink As String

SubmitLink = Target.Offset(, -8).Value

answer = MsgBox("Do you wish to save this change. An Email will be sent to the User", vbYesNo, "Save the change")

If answer = vbNo Then Cancel = True
If answer = vbYes Then
'open outlook type stuff
Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OlObjects = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set newmsg = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
'add recipients
'newmsg.Recipients.Add ("Name Here")
newmsg.Recipients.Add Worksheets("Coordinator").Range("Q4").Value
'add subject
newmsg.Subject = Worksheets("Coordinator").Range("O3").Value
'add body
newmsg.Body = "Dear User, New Submittal ( " & SubmitLink & " ) has been Added in Submittal Log. Please Investigate the Change" & vbLf & vbLf & vbLf & "Sincerely," & vbLf & "logs department"

newmsg.Display 'display
newmsg.Send 'send message
'give conformation of sent message
MsgBox "Modification confirmed", , "Confirmation"



End If
   '     MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."

End If
End Sub
```